# Colab pro timeouts

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm implementing a paper in colab rn with 160000 iterations where each iteration takes about 2-3 seconds which means with normal colab i should be finished in about 5-6 days, but i get timed out most of the time at around 5 hours, probably cause I'm using alot of ressources, then I have to wait 12 hours to train again.

My question is, If I'd get colab pro, will i get full 24 hours most of the time or will I get timed out much earlier and is the timeout duration the same as in colab free?

Comment: can I ask you what is the paper that you are implementing,is it a ML paper?

Comment: yea of course, it's the Arbitrary Style Transfer paper for neural style transfer, 160000 is just the absolute max, probably more like 30k-50k but that would still be a huge amount of time

Comment: That one with "with Adaptive Instance Normalization" or is it something else?

Comment: exactly that one

Comment: I assume you will TensorFlow to build and train the model.If you have already build model and if you could find any previous model build on the Tensorflow with pre-trained weights,you can use it as Transfer Learning for your model. If you want to learn,just check for few 1000 iterations,no need to train it again from scratch

Comment: Yea you're probably right that for this application that would be best, but I'm planning on implementing more recent papers soon where you won't find pretrained weights that easily, this is more of a question if colab pro can be used for serious deep learning projects.

Comment: I don't know if Colab Pro will be right choice for you,But there are AWS and and other cloud services that can provide computing power,I think I will too wait for someone else to answer your questions

Comment: Yea thanks alot for your input, aws for example would be the next step but if i could get away with colab pro I'd be happier ^^

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer that you train your model for a few epochs first ---> save it ---> reload it and then train again.